# Strange /_next/data/[hash]/xxx.json requests

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Whenever a users goes to a route, I can see that requests are being sent to `https://[project-url.com]/_next/data/[hash]/[route].json` which return a 403.

These requests are also being sent when ran on local and on dev deployments which return 200, but only returns 403 on prod. (our project uses aws for deployments as far as I'm concerned). This actually causes no issues *practically*, but the 403 error is bothering me.

I have checked for similar issues online which return a 404, but I haven't seen 403.

I have been [advised](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/38414#discussioncomment-8861684) to replace next/link tags with good ol' a tags, but I'm not sure how that would work. Btw, our project does not use getServerSideProps or getInitialProps.

Any ideas what could be causing this and how do I stop it from sending these requests?